# WPF set UserControl size to MainWindow container size

Tags: wpf, layout, user-controls

I have a mainWindow that has a menu and container to place a userControl depending on menu button click. 
dpmain in a StackPanel in a Grid, Width and Height is Auto, Horisontal and Vertical
Alignments are Stretch everywhere in my application

dpMain.Children.Clear();
dpMain.Children.Add(element);

UserControl is a big datagrid, when I add Userconrol to mainform, mainform resizing to the size of the grid,
but I actually need the grid be the size of Actual size of the StackPanel, and be able to resize when I resize the Main form.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A StackPanel is not a suitable panel for this as it only allows stretching in one direction. If you have just one control try to replace the whole panel with it.

Comment: I have other controls on the MainForm and a container for userControl. What type of container (panel) should I use then?

Comment: Unless there are more controls, none. The StackPanel has to be the content or child of some other control, make the UserControl take its place. As long as the UserControl is a child of a StackPanel it will never be able to stretch in both directions automatically. What you said about the actual size may be a solution but not a very elegant one as it just overrides the layout of a panel that should not be used for single elements in the first place.

Comment: As i said twice now, replace the StackPanel with your UserControl, or provide a clearer vision of the logical tree of your window as i might not have gotten it from your description.

Comment: this is the layout of my MainForm
<Window ...
   SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
...
  <DockPanel>
     <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25">
...
     </Menu>
     <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Height="25"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
...
     </StatusBar>
     <igOutlookBar:XamOutlookBar Name="barNav"
         DockPanel.Dock="Left"
         Width="200" MinWidth="200" Padding="0">
...
     </igOutlookBar:XamOutlookBar>
     <Grid Name="dpMain" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
     </Grid>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>

Comment: I do not see any stackpanels there at all, what is the problem?